# Using a get_url request removes part of the functionality of my dashboard

Tags: python

I have a very specific problem with this program I'm working on, I'll try to explain it as clearly as possible.

The idea I have is to have my app (gwtc-dash) let users select an event, and for the app to give them specific information about the event they selected. Here is the app running now for an example: https://gwtc-dash.streamlit.app/

Now the user should have three options when selecting an event, either selecting one from the drop down menu, selecting one from clicking on one of the data points in the chart, or I want to enable the ability to have the event load via a url from another site, for example if I wanted to show the information for event GW151012 I would give them this link: https://gwtc-dash.streamlit.app/?event_name=GW151012

My first two options work perfectly fine, the issue I'm having is with the URL option. Currently if I give the user a link, it will pull up the event from the URL and fill in the rest of the charts with that specific event data. however for some reason it disables the user the ability to click on a point in the chart, it will not load any data for an event if you click on a point, I've tried all sorts of different ways to enable this but I'm totally stuck.

Here is a link to my full file:

https://github.com/ctrejocaltech/LIGO/blob/755ab8c0976ef83440487bb9f9414fead5c12c71/GWC/test3.py

Here is a copy of the relevant code, I know it's a lot of code but it's a pretty big project, any help would be greatly appreciated, I'll try to break it up as best as I can:

This first part of my code loads all my data that I need, you can see where I get the event url from right at the top

```
url = st.experimental_get_query_params()

# Get specific parameter values, e.g., event_name
event_url = url.get("event_name", ["default_event"])[0]
st.write(event_url)

# Fetch the data from the URL and load it into a DataFrame
@st.cache_data
def load_and_group_data():
    df = pd.read_csv("https://gwosc.org/eventapi/csv/allevents/")
    
    catalogs = ['GWTC', 'GWTC-1-confident', 'GWTC-2', 'GWTC-2.1-confident', 'GWTC-3-confident', 'O3_Discovery_Papers']
    
    grouped_data = {}
    
    for catalog in catalogs:
        if catalog == 'GWTC':
            event_data = df[df['catalog.shortName'].str.contains('confident', case=False)]
        else:
            event_data = df[(df['catalog.shortName'] == catalog)]
        grouped_data[catalog] = event_data

    return grouped_data

grouped_data = load_and_group_data()
st.divider()
#create top row columns for selectbox and charts
col1, col2, col3 = st.columns(3)

with col1:
    selected_cat = st.selectbox('Select an Event Catalog (Defaults to GWTC)', grouped_data.keys())
    if selected_cat in grouped_data:
        event_df = grouped_data[selected_cat]

# Eliminate rows with missing mass_1_source or mass_2_source
event_df = event_df.dropna(subset=['mass_1_source', 'mass_2_source'])
event_df['total_mass_source'] = event_df['mass_1_source'] + event_df['mass_2_source'] #fix missing mass issue
event_df.to_excel('updated_GWTC.xlsx', index=False)
updated_excel = 'updated_GWTC.xlsx'

# Loads df to use for the rest of the dash
df = pd.read_excel(updated_excel)
```

Eventually I'm left with df which is the data that contains the names of the catalogs I want to use to fill in the rest of my charts with.

This next part filters out the data further and checks to see if the event_url is in my event_options and to make sure if the event_url is in the list.

```
# Sort mass for event type distribution
def categorize_event(row):
    if row['mass_1_source'] < 3 and row['mass_2_source'] < 3:
        return 'Binary Neutron Star'
    elif row['mass_1_source'] >= 3 and row['mass_2_source'] >= 3:
        return 'Binary Black Hole'
    else:
        return 'Neutron Star - Black Hole'
df['Event'] = df.apply(categorize_event, axis=1)

# Group data by event type and count occurrences
grouped_df = df.groupby('Event').size().reset_index(name='Count')


# Function to filter event options based on input prefix
def filter_event_options(prefix):
    return df[df['commonName'].str.startswith(prefix)]['commonName'].tolist()

# Get the list of event options
event_options = filter_event_options("")

# Initialize selected event name
selected_event_name = ""

# If there's an event URL, try to locate it in the dropdown options
if event_url and event_url in event_options:
    selected_event_name = event_url
```

This part here is my event chart that allows users to click on a data point to generate the event data and it has the event input option if users want to type in a name instead:

```
#MAIN CHART FOR USER INPUT
event_chart = px.scatter(df, x="mass_1_source", y="mass_2_source", color="network_matched_filter_snr", labels={
    "network_matched_filter_snr": "Network SNR",
    "luminosity_distance": "Luminosity Distance (Mpc)",
    "commonName": "Name",
    "mass_1_source": "Mass 1",
    "mass_2_source": "Mass 2", 
}, title= "Event Catalog of source-frame component masses m<sub>(i)</sub>", color_continuous_scale = "dense", hover_data=["commonName"])

# Create the selectbox with options
event_input = st.selectbox(
    "If you want to look up a specific Event, type the name below or click on an event in the chart below to populate more information.",
    [""] + event_options,  # Add an empty option as the default
    key="event_input",
    index=event_options.index(selected_event_name) if selected_event_name else 0  # Set the default index based on the selected_event_name
)
# Initialize select_event as an empty list
select_event = [event_url]
#User Selection
select_event = plotly_events(event_chart, click_event=True)
```

Now here is where I'm stuck, it will not allow the user to select an event from my select_event = plotly_events option if I have an event_url, if there isn't an event_url the chart works perfectly fine.

```
def generate_event_charts(event_name=None):
    event_name = None  # Initialize event_name

    if event_name:
        selected_event_name = event_name
    else:
        if event_input:  # Check if event_input is not empty
            selected_event_name = event_input  # Update selected_event_name based on user input
            selected_event_row = df[df['commonName'] == selected_event_name]

            if not selected_event_row.empty:
                selected_x = selected_event_row['mass_1_source'].values[0]
                selected_y = selected_event_row['mass_2_source'].values[0]
                select_event = [{'x': selected_x, 'y': selected_y}]
            else:
                selected_event_name = "Click on an Event"
        else:
            selected_event_name = "Click on an Event"

    if selected_event_name != "Click on an Event":
        selected_event_row = df[df['commonName'] == selected_event_name]

        if not selected_event_row.empty:
            selected_x = selected_event_row['mass_1_source'].values[0]
            selected_y = selected_event_row['mass_2_source'].values[0]
            select_event = [{'x': selected_x, 'y': selected_y}]
        else:
            selected_event_name = "Click on an Event"

    if select_event:
        # Retrieve clicked x and y values
        clicked_x = select_event[0]['x']
        clicked_y = select_event[0]['y']

        # Find the row in the DataFrame that matches the clicked x and y values
        selected_row = df[(df["mass_1_source"] == clicked_x) & (df["mass_2_source"] == clicked_y)]

        if not selected_row.empty:
            selected_common_name = selected_row["commonName"].values[0]
            event_name = selected_common_name
            if gps_info := event_gps(event_name):
                mass_1 = selected_row['mass_1_source'].values[0]
                mass_2 = selected_row['mass_2_source'].values[0]
                dist = selected_row['luminosity_distance'].values[0]
                total_mass_source = selected_row['total_mass_source'].values[0]
                snr = selected_row['network_matched_filter_snr'].values[0]
                chirp = selected_row['chirp_mass'].values[0]
            else:
                st.write("GPS Information not available for the selected event.")  

    return event_name, gps_info, mass_1, mass_2, dist, total_mass_source, snr, chirp  # Return event_name at the end of the function
```

This is the part of the code that is supposed to take the event the user has selected, either by URL, from input or from the chart click, and generate different charts.

```
#CHARTS WITH USER INPUT
if select_event:    
    st.divider()
    st.markdown('### EVENT METRICS for the selected event: ' + event_name)
    st.write("GPS Time:", gps_info, "is the end time or merger time of the event in GPS seconds.")
    st.write('The :red[red line |] indicates the largest value found to date for each category.')
    st.write('The :blue[[blue area]] indicates the margin of error for each source.')
    st.write('Note: Some events may not have error information.')
    ##Gauge Indicators
    total_mass_lower = selected_row['total_mass_source_lower'].values[0] + selected_row['total_mass_source'].values[0] 
    total_mass_upper = selected_row['total_mass_source_upper'].values[0] + selected_row['total_mass_source'].values[0]    
    total_mass = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
    mode = "gauge+number",
    value = total_mass_source,
    number = {"suffix": "M<sub>☉</sub>"},
    title = {'text': "Total Mass (M<sub>☉</sub>)"},
    gauge = {'axis': {'range': [None, 250]},
            'bar': {'color': "#4751a5"},             
            'steps' : [
                {'range': [total_mass_source, total_mass_upper], 'color': "lightskyblue"},
                {'range': [total_mass_source, total_mass_lower], 'color': "lightskyblue"}],             
            'bgcolor': "white",
            'threshold' : {'line': {'color': "red", 'width': 4}, 'thickness': 0.75, 'value': 181}},
    domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]}
    ))
```

The way my code currently runs, it says that the values event_name, gps_info, selected_row, total_mass_source etc aren't defined. I'm not sure how else to approach this or what I'm missing, if I should rebuild my code a different way. I'm at a loss, any help would be greatly appreciated